# jQuery Smooth Scroll cross-browser problem

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I have a small snippet of code to produce a smooth scroll to anchor tags and back again. My site design has a fixed header of height 170px. So to compensate for this the java has been modified as below.

```
var jump=function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var target = $(this).attr("href");
   $('html,body').animate(
   {
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-170 // modification
   },1000,function()
   {
      location.hash = target;
   });
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
   return false;
});
```

This code works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but in IE & Firefox it scrolls to the intended location and jumps 170px further down the page.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: `location.hash = target;` wouldn't that produce double hashes? like ##bla? as target would be something like '#bla' and location.hash adds the hash automatically but I could be wrong ...

Comment: Try moving the `return false;` from `document.ready()` to `jump()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when your animation finishes, you set `location.hash` which makes the browser jump to the anchor. As a simple workaround, don't prevent the hash change on the click, save the current scroll position instead. That way your browser would jump to the hash straight away.

To animate the whole thing, you can catch the `hashchange` event, and immediately jump back where you've left off and animate the transition to your heart's content.

Older browsers might experience some flicker, see if it's accaptable for you, worth a try.

```
var scrollFrom = 0;

$('a[href*=#]').click(function(e){
    scrollFrom = $(window).scrollTop();
});

$(window).bind('hashchange',function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollFrom);
    var target = '#' + location.hash.replace(/#/,'');
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-170 // modification
    },1000);
});
```

Alternatively you can do it your way, just prefix the actual IDs of your anchors in the markup to prevent the browser automatically jumping there, then add the prefix to the clicked hash to locate the element with a selector.

Also see @fudgey's answer for cleaning up your `'html,body'` selector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this option and it works across browsers although it has created a new bug. This time it always scrolls from the top. So in other words, the anchor link will scroll down the page as it should, but then if I use a "back to top" link, this will jump to the top and then scroll down to the #top tag rather than scrolling upwards. Any ideas? And thanks to the others for your replies!

Comment: How are you scrolling to the top? If I just set up two anchors, it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PfDrq/ If you're using "#" as your href, make sure you set the `target` variable accordingly, as your selector will just be `'#'`.

Comment: Its a mystery! I have edited your jsfiddle so that it replicated my html and it works fine, yet my page still jumps to the top first?? See here: http://jsfiddle.net/PfDrq/12/

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for (event the 170 offset!) but I have noticed that when you click the same link twice the second time it doesn't work, no animation, no offset. This happens on the jsfiddle examples too. I have a feeling it has something to do with binding the animation to a change in the window url but because there hasn't been a change it skips that... just don't have the js skills to know how to fix that.

Comment: Someone at work helped me out. We worked out we needed to check if the url had a hash already and fire hashchange if true. So we added:
if (window.location.hash.length) {$(window).trigger('hashchange');} to the .click function.

Comment: Also, not sure what the purpose of '#' + location.hash.replace(/#/,''); was as you're adding the # and then removing it? Wouldn't location.hash be the same?

Comment: @Daniel: At the time I wrote this bit of code, there was an inconsistency across browsers, some included the `#` in `location.hash`, some didn't. So I thought it's safer to remove it, if it's there, then add it back for the jQuery ID selection.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I see:

1. When you set the hash in the callback function, it makes the page jump to the anchor. So, the best solution, I think, would be to have a margin-bottom under your anchor. That way you don't need to subtract out the 170 pixels, and the hash change in the callback won't make the page jump.
2. The second problem is using `$('html,body')` for scrolling. Opera seems to treat both as separate elements, so you will see the page scroll twice. Here is a nice [cross-browser fix](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/18/jquery-smooth-scroll-bugs.html).